# Raise ValueError(f"Could not load model {model} with any of the following classes: {class_tuple}.")

Tags: python, pytorch, model, pipeline, summarization

I am trying to make a text summarization tool using facebook/bart-large-cnn model. I tried the same code in windows and it worked perfectly, now, I am trying the same code in MAC and I am getting below error.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/shubhamsingh/Desktop/Python Udemy Tutorial/Summarizer/summary.py", line 5, in <module>
    summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="facebook/bart-large-cnn")
                 ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/__init__.py", line 776, in pipeline
    framework, model = infer_framework_load_model(
                       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/site-packages/transformers/pipelines/base.py", line 271, in infer_framework_load_model
    raise ValueError(f"Could not load model {model} with any of the following classes: {class_tuple}.")
ValueError: Could not load model facebook/bart-large-cnn with any of the following classes: (<class 'transformers.models.auto.modeling_auto.AutoModelForSeq2SeqLM'>, <class 'transformers.models.bart.modeling_bart.BartForConditionalGeneration'>).
```

My code

```
from transformers import pipeline
import torch

import os

summarizer = pipeline("summarization", model="facebook/bart-large-cnn")
def summarize_text(text: str, max_len: int) -> str:
    try:
        summary = summarizer(text, max_length=max_len, min_length=10, do_sample=False)
        return summary[0]["summary_text"]
    except IndexError as ex:
        
        return summarize_text(text=text[:(len(text) // 2)], max_len=max_len//2) + summarize_text(text=text[(len(text) // 2):], max_len=max_len//2)

print(summarize_text(ANY_TEXT, max_len=1024))
```

Now, I know I need latest pip, pytorch library installed which I already have

- Python --version 3.11.2
- pip --version 23.0.1
- torch --version 2.0.0

Let me know if you need anymore info.

Thank you.